# Bash can't find an existing file

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have a Debian Wheezy Linux, which gives me this most puzzling output:

```
root@server:~# ls -al /opt/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/bin/java
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7718 Dec 19 03:13 /opt/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/bin/java
root@server:~# /opt/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/bin/java
-bash: /opt/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

So it can see the java executable (verified via cat that it is an executable indeed) but can't see it the same time. Any pointers?

Comment: I have tried what the linked answer says but couldn't get any closer. Upon trying to install `libc6-i386`, I was informed that only `libc6` exists but that is already installed on this machine.
Running `eu-readelf` on the executable gave a different result than that one, including this line: `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]`

Comment: Is this question still a duplicate, even if the source of the error is different than of the other one? In my previous comment I have outlined why and how did those answers prove to be not useful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out we have installed a wrong version of java:

```
jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

instead of the correct

```
jdk-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

one. The nature and cause of the error message still eludes me though.